# Filtering out a row value based on column value using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How to filter out a row value in a column B, if another column C has a specific text say "ABC" ? in this case "google.com" would be filtered out.

```
       A      B              C      D
0   True   facebook.com    kxy     19999
1   True   google.com      ABC     21212
2  False   yahoo.com       PoP     3213231
```

Everytime there is "ABC" in Col C, row value from col B should be appended in a list.

pseudocode:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('xyz.csv')

path = []


for value in dataset.C:
    if dataset['C'] == 'abc':
        #append path with row value of Col B 
    else:
        #not append path
```

Comment: `s='ABC'` , `path=df.loc[df['C'].eq(s),'B'].tolist()` ? if not exact match use `df.loc[df['C'].str.contains(s),'B'].tolist()`

Answer (score 4):

```py
path = dataset.loc[dataset.C == 'ABC', 'B'].tolist()
```

will give you the desired list in one go.

Answer (score 1):

as an alternative you can use `where` and `list`:

```
path = list(data.B.where(data.C == 'ABC').dropna())
print(path)
# ['google.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

`inds` will be a pandas series with boolean values, indicating whether a row's value in column 'C' is equal to 'ABC'.

Once we know that, we can subset `dataset` and take the values of column 'B':

```
inds = dataset['C'] == 'ABC'
list(dataset.loc[inds, 'B'])
```

Answer (score 0):

> Direct asnwer:

```
filtered_values = dataset.loc[dataset["C"]=='ABC']['B'].tolist()
```

**For understanding purposes:**

First get the rows where C="ABC"

```
filtered_rows = dataset.loc[dataset["C"]=='ABC']

filtered_rows
```

**Output:**

```
    A       B           C   D
1   True    google.com  ABC 21212
```

From these rows get the values of only column B and convert this Series into a list with `.tolist()` function

```
filtered_values = filtered_rows["B"].tolist()

filtered_values
```

**Output:**

```
['google.com']
```